# Python/Django - How to debug variables

Tags: python, django, debugging

I'm pretty new to the Python/Django world and I need to dump some variables (right after model calling for example) and display all the informations about that specific variable to the user (the developer, in my case, me).

In PHP we are used to do "var_dump($some_var); die;"

But in my case, I can't find a way to achieve just that, and I'm pretty sure that's simple because obviously every django/python developer are able to do that !

Comment: You can simply use the debugger and set breakpoints to do so, e.g. using pycharm as IDE.

Comment: There is no way to get variables informations other than debugging via the IDE in python/django ?

Comment: At least that is the recommended way. Of course you can add print(...) statements (or pprint for output that looks nicer). When working with templates, you could also show the variables' contents there.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the following line after the model
‘import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()’

For more information see [this tutorial](https://hasil-sharma.github.io/2017-05-13-python-ipdb/)